# Difference between If-else and Case statement in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, code-design, rtl

I want to understand how different constructs in VHDL code are synthesized in RTL.

- Can anyone tell me the difference between **If-Else** construct and
  **Case statement** constructs of a process in VHDL in terms of how the code is inferenced into RTL circuit by the synthesis tool ?
- Do consider the case of **multiple nested if-else** and **mixing
  case-statements with if-else** construct inside a process.
- Also when to use which construct ?

PS: I have seen a related question "Multiple if statements in process in vhdl" but that doesn't answer my question in anyway.

Comment: I can't comment on how the physical gates would be configured, but in most compilers that emit x86 assembly an if-else usually exists as a single check with a conditional jump (e.g. jg, jl, jz, jnz, etc.), whereas switch organises the cases in numeric order and does iterative `dec` / `jz` instructions, which is much more efficient. Perhaps a similar optimisation is applied here.

Comment: @Polynomial The behavior of If-else and case are significantly different in hardware languages compared to your typical linear programming. Op-code optimizations are not very relevant since the HDL statement executes "instantly".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me the difference between If-Else construct and Case statement constructs of a process in VHDL in terms of how the code is inferenced into RTL circuit by the synthesis tool ?

The `if-elsif-else` construct infers a priority routing network:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f60mk4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This corresponds to

```
if bool_expr_1 then
    sig <= val_expr_1;
elsif bool_expr_2 then
    sig <= val_expr_2;
elsif bool_expr_3 then
    sig <= val_expr_3;
else
    sig <= val_expr_4;
end if;
```

The `case` construct, on the other hand, infers a big ol' mux:

[image]

This corresponds to

```
case case_expr is
  when c0 =>
    sig <= val_expr_0;
  when c1 =>
    sig <= val_expr_1;
  when c2 =>
    sig <= val_expr_2;
      ...
  when others =>
    sig <= val_expr_N;
end case;
```

Obviously these are very simplified designs with only one value expression, resulting in one output.

> Do consider the case of multiple nested if-else and mixing case-statements with if-else construct inside a process.

Per the above, you can see how they would nest/mix.

> Also when to use which construct ?

Since `if-else` infers priority, it should be used when more than one input condition could occur. Using `case`, one the other hand, is appropriate when the inputs are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I understand that case statment works only for single input condition and if-else can work for multiple input conditions. But both constructs essentially generate muxes(in absence of clk). Isn't it possible that logic synthesis may optimize single-input if-else to a single big mux instead of chain of muxes ? Also, what is a priority routing network ...isn't this simply chain of muxes instead of 1 big mux ?

Comment: Additionally, when we have a process sensitive to a clock, if-else can generate sequential elements such as registers, latches etc. Can a case statement also generate sequential logic ?

Comment: Yes, a priority routing network is exactly that - a chain of muxes. The nature of the `if-else` construct, however, is where that chain arises. The first condition *must* fail for the second condition to be tested. This is not the case for, er, the `case` construct, and this is why an `if-else` statement could not be synthesized as a single large mux.

Comment: And yes, a `case` statement can generate sequential logic as well. I found ["Real World VHDL"](http://userweb.eng.gla.ac.uk/scott.roy/DCD3/03_VHDL_Real%20World.pdf), a series of lecture slides from the University of Glasgow, which may be helpful to you.

Comment: This is a good reference.

Comment: Angelo Stavrow: Does this mean, that the case-example has less delay from input to output than the if/else-case?

Answer (score 5):

In [this old blog post](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2010/03/is-case-statement-more-efficient-than.html), the author wrote and synthesized two functionally equivalent versions of VHDL code. One using if-else, the other using case. The result:

> I synthesized this code and got the exact results.Even the RTL
>   schematic was exactly same for both of the programs.

And his conclusion:

> This shows that 'case' and 'if...elsif...else' statements are both
>   equally efficient.But if you want to write a clear code,then you
>   better use 'case'.'case' is very useful when the output depends upon a
>   large number of conditions.But if the number of conditions are very
>   small(2 or 3) then you can use 'if..elseif..else'.

There are also [dozens of posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=switch+case+versus+if+else) on this subject on Stack Overflow for every conceivable language. The conclusion is generally the same, that there is no difference performance-wise. Occasionally, if there is a large number of cases, a compiler may be smart enough to create a look-up table which would yield slightly better performance.

A VHDL synthesizer may be able to do the something similar. But you would still need a large number of cases in which case (pun intended) you would probably want to use a case statement anyways as it provides better readability where there is a large number of options.